# S3 head object but signature does not match

Tags: linux, curl, amazon-s3

I want to use curl to head objects in s3.

code:

```
s3key=xxxxx... (s3 key)
s3skey=xxxxxx...(secret key)
bucket=xxx
file=/xx.txt
date=$(date +"%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")
string="HEAD\n\n\n$date\n/$bucket$file"
signature=$(/bin/echo -en $string | openssl sha1 -hmac $s3skey -binary | base64)
curl -H "Host: $bucket.s3.amazonaws.com" \
    -H "Date: $date" \
    -H "Authorization: AWS $s3key:$signature" \
 https://$bucket.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com$file
```

it always shows request signature we calculate does not match the signature you provided. I dont know why?

If I change to GET from HEAD , it will work and I got the objects.
I don't understand which part of signature is wrong

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature, as you realize, includes the http method (e.g. `GET`, `HEAD`) that the request will be using... but the signing process is a one-way process (using an HMAC digest), so the recipient of the signature (S3) has no way of knowing what parameters you used when signing the request -- it only knows that, based on the request you are making, the signature you provided doesn't match it.

The problem here is that you are creating a signature for a `HEAD` request, but curl is still *making* a `GET` request.  You can see this yourself by using `curl -v`.

The solution is to tell curl to actually make a `HEAD` request, and this is done with `curl -I`.